# Successives canvas manipulations optimization

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, pixel, onload

Hi I making an app where I have to manipulate some png: extract some color, create some outline etc...

Each time I repeat the same process:

1. Wait for image load in DOM
2. Create a new canvas with size
3. Add context2D
4. DrawImage
5. GetImageData
6. Do some stuff with a loop through all data pixel
7. Put the new stuff (putImageData) in a empty pixel data array (create with createImageData)
8. Link it to a new canvas
9. Create anew image from this canvas
10. repeat

For example:

```
var imgColor = new Image();
imgColor.src = this[`canvasColor${color}`].toDataURL("image/png");

// wait for load of this new color image
imgColor.onload = () => {
  this[`canvasColorAndOutline${color}`].width = width;
  this[`canvasColorAndOutline${color}`].height = height;
  var outlineAndColorCtx = this[`canvasColorAndOutline${color}`].getContext("2d");
  var dArr = [-1, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], // offset array
    s = this.state.outlineThickness,  // thickness
    i = 0,  // iterator
    x = 0,  // final position
    y = 0;

  // draw images at offsets from the array scaled by s
  for (; i < dArr.length; i += 2) {

    outlineAndColorCtx.drawImage(imgColor, x + dArr[i] * s, y + dArr[i + 1] * s);
  }

  // fill with color
  outlineAndColorCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
  outlineAndColorCtx.fillStyle = "YELLOW";
  outlineAndColorCtx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

  // draw original image in normal mode
  outlineAndColorCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  outlineAndColorCtx.drawImage(imgColor, x, y);

  ///////////////
  // THIRD STEP : remove the white to keep the outline
  //////////////

  // create a new image with this color context to work on
  var imgOutline = new Image();
  imgOutline.src = this[`canvasColorAndOutline${color}`].toDataURL("image/png");
  imgOutline.onload = () => {
    var imageDataOutlineAndColor = outlineAndColorCtx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height)
    this[`canvasOutline${color}`].width = width;
    this[`canvasOutline${color}`].height = height;
    const outlineCtx = this[`canvasOutline${color}`].getContext("2d");
    const imageDataOutline = outlineCtx.createImageData(width, height);

    for (let i = 0; i < imageDataOutlineAndColor.data.length; i += 4) {

      if (
        (imageDataOutlineAndColor.data[i + 0] > 100) &&
        (imageDataOutlineAndColor.data[i + 1] > 100) &&
        (imageDataOutlineAndColor.data[i + 2] < 5) &&
        (imageDataOutlineAndColor.data[i + 3] != 0)
      ) {
        imageDataOutline.data[i + 0] = 255;
        imageDataOutline.data[i + 1] = 255;
        imageDataOutline.data[i + 2] = 0;
        imageDataOutline.data[i + 3] = 255;
      }
    }
    outlineCtx.putImageData(imageDataOutline, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

**My question is**: Is there a way the shortcut step 7,8,9 to avoid the time of img.load? and directly use the context? 
So I will use the same context all the time, it is just modify in each process step. 
And more globally, is there a way to optimize it?

Comment: You could optmise it by just placing your image data back onto your original canvas and then starting the next step; keeping only 1 canvas in memory at any time.

Comment: Yeah I understand what you mean, but in this case I want to keep all canvas I generate. 
But for example, could it be possible to :
Launch the code to create a canvas and at the end :
- Create a new canvas 
- and at the same time continue the next step without waiting the canvas creation where we have to wait the image load in the canvas
?

Comment: Step 1 is really img.src = canvas.toDataURL? If at the begining you have canvases, then you don't need a single img and can do everything synchronously: drawImage accepts a canvas a source.

Comment: In fact there are several way to start, but initialy I put a tag <img> with the image I want to process and I wait the load of this tag to begin.

you mean we could do contextType.drawImage(imageType,0,0) and canvasType.drawImage(imageType,0,0) ?

Comment: I mean never do img.src = canvas.toDataURL(); Instead replace the img with the canvas directly. Img is for external resources. If you get the image from a canvas, it is no more external and doesn't need an img. And yes, you can drawImage(canvas.x.y)